# I have repeatedly asked for no-claims certificate from previous insurer, but have not received, what can I do?

Tags: united-kingdom, car-insurance

I have been insured with the same car insurance company for three years and this year I decided to find a cheaper insurer, which I did. I am now one month into my policy with the new insurance company and they have asked that I send proof of my no-claims discount (as a certificate). I have repeatedly asked my old insurer on a number of occasions for this certificate and so far I have received a certificate that I have only 1 year of No-claims, much to my frustration.

I feel incredibly frustrated with my old insurer as they have not sent me the correct certificate on two occasions.
What can I do realistically in order to settle this? Can I go to the ombudsman?

EDIT: I have recently been notified by my new insurer that my premium will double as I have not sent in proof of my no-claims.

Comment: Did your old insurer send you a renewal notice that listed your no-claims?

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica No, I can’t find any evidence that they did

Comment: Have you been the main driver on your old insurance policy for the last three years? If you were a named driver for two of those and the main driver for one year, that could explain the one year no-claims certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle you can complain to the Financial Ombudsman about problems with your no-claims bonus. For example [here](https://www.financial-ombudsman.org.uk/files/266351/DRN8337004.pdf) is a case where someone was unfairly denied a no-claims bonus and provided substantial compensation because he ended up not being able to use his car as he couldn't afford to insure it. If you could insure your car but just had to pay more you could probably expect the Ombudsman to order the old insurer to pay you any extra costs you incurred (if your claim was upheld).

That said I've had quite mixed experiences with the Ombudsman and a [recent documentary](https://www.channel4.com/press/news/investigation-fos-finds-staff-severe-lack-training)  suggests they have a widespread problem with poor training and staff rushing decisions. So I wouldn't count on them reaching a fair decision.

Before you go to the Ombudsman you should complain to the old insurer and give them 8 weeks to respond. I'd suggest also writing to your new insurer explaining the situation and asking them if you can get a refund if you do later provide the proof.